# Joomla Modal box popup code works in article, but not in code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla, conflict

This question goes for Joomla developers, or enthusiasts.
Unfortunately there is no way to reproduce this scenario on js fiddle website.
I have the following code:

```
    <!-- AQUI COMEÇA O MODAL POPUP, QUE É O POPUP BUILTIN DO JOOMLA AO ESTILO LIGHTBOX -->
<!-- Esta parte ativa a função -->
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal', 'a.modal'); ?><!-- Esta parte utiliza javascript para transformar o layout do popup em um fluido -->
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();

    //ID of container
    $('a#modal_info').attr('rel','{handler: "iframe", size: {x: '+(width-(width*0.03))+', y: '+(height-(height*0.20))+'}}');
    });</script>

    <!-- Esta parte é o Link para fazer a chamada -->

    <div class="modal barradofundo" onclick="window.location.href = this.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;">

    <div id="bf1"><img id="bf1img" src="/images/images201605/Coin-icon-e.png" alt="Dinheiro" border="0"></div>
    <!-- Esta parte é o Link para fazer a chamada -->
    <div id="bf2"><span>Saia da crise agora mesmo, destaque-se e ganhe muito dinheiro!</span>
    </div>
    <div id="bf3"><a id="modal_info" href="/va/filetobeloaded.html" class="modal catalogobotao2">SAIBA +</a></div>

    </div>

    <div class="barradofundoespaco"></div>
```

What that code does is to open a modal box popup that uses a fluid a layout, in other words, it's like a lightbox that fits window.

Inside that box it loads an external page.
The `{source}` tag is from Sourcerer Plugin, which is used to load javascript, HTML or php inside any part of the site.

It works just fine when used inside an article, but when I try using it in a custom module, it doesn't work, it not even works on other modules that accept php and HTML.
I have jQuery enabled, properly configured and have not conflicts showing in the console. It looks like it's a problem with the module.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:
Found out that using the  `<?php JHTML::_('behavior.modal', 'a.modal'); ?>` in the `index.php` file of the template, I was able to put it to work. But the problem is that I can't hack the code, as I'll lose the hack after a system's update.